# Rider weight limits regarding a bicycle purchase

Tags: weight, fitness

So I’m a 5’9 little over 400lbs, and I’m changing my life style. I’m eating better and swimming for exercise. Exercise is hard so I want to start riding a bike also. I’m only going to be riding on flat land, no curbs or hills. I’m looking at a Mongoose Dolomite fat tire. It’s about 300$ which is where I’d like to be price range, but the manufacturer weight limit is 350. Will it support me? I looked into Zike and those bikes are 2500-5000$. I’m not riding for sport or doing marathons. Just looking to ride 3-4 miles every few days on flat ground. Please any info would help, even spending 300 on this mongoose will be a waste if I can’t use it the way I need to or it breaks.

Comment: While distinct from the question you are trying to ask, the absurdly wide, low pressure tires of "fat" bikes are really intended for unique terrain like beach sand or possibly snow.  On a paved or packed dirt surface they are just wasted effort.  For general upright position knock-around on multi-use paths either paved or unpaved, quiet roads, etc you probably want a sturdy "hybrid" not a "fat bike"

Comment: A bike which is "rated" for 350 pounds should be able to handle 400 if you are reasonably gentle with it.  You don't want a narrow-tire bike, but you probably don't need an absurdly fat-tire one either.  Do be sure to keep the tire pressure on the high end of its rating.

Comment: Now may be a good time to let the OP know 3-4 miles daily on flat ground is going to do very little for weight loss. I'm currently doing 15 miles daily and that's over a mixture of flat and hills. The weight loss over a month is minimal. I don't want to put the OP off riding but he needs to be aware cycling isn't the best route for weight loss and maybe better off doing a brisk walk daily.

Comment: @DanK but 3-4 miles/day from a base of nothing/exercise being a struggle is an important step in becoming more active.  The first step in major weight loss is often to build up some tolerance to exercise so absolutely anything helps (and riding should be easier on the joints than walking, even if "brisk" is an option).  Even before any weight is lost there will be health benefits, so well done and good luck to the OP.

Comment: @ChrisStratton's point (and Daniel's) is true, but a fatbike has the advantage that the shock loads (which to some extent determine the durability) will be significantly reduced compared to a hybrid, due to the cushioning from the tyres.  That would also be true of a full-sus MTB but you wouldn't get helpful suspension for this case in this price bracket.  On the other hand a hybrid can be fitted with wheels and tyres more suited to heavy touring or even a tandem

Comment: Exercise for weight loss is doomed to fail. Over simplifying it a lot, as you exercise more, your appetite increases, (as a rough guide 1kg of body fat is is 7,800Cal and will take 11 hours at 200W - a fit rider can maintain 200W for an hour) - a rider doing 3 1 hour rides a week will take 4 weeks to burn that fat. Reducing input by just 300Cal () two cans of soft drink) a day has the same effect.     Exercise for the purpose of health is incredibly important, as is weight loss for health purposes(for obese people). But this does not mean that exercise for weight loss is important.

Comment: @Chris H from the point of exercising from a base of nothing then yes agreed every little helps but the OP said he was swimming, he will benefit more from loosing weight just by swimming more. If the OP wants to ride 3 or 4 miles then good on him. All I was pointing out was the OP won't see many gains to cycling over what he already doing.

Comment: GCN has just posted a video of [tips for weight loss with cycling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fne9-LW0ivc). (They mention power meters; those are expensive so probably not something that's worth it for a few miles a day.)

Comment: Riding bikes makes people happier. Being happier helps with weight loss. OP I wish you many wonderful miles with your new bike!

Comment: Whilst personally I wouldn't recommend exceeding the manufacturers weight limit, the reviews on amazon suggest a few users have done so successfully: https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx29ZV5UXGT9397/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza

Answer (score 5):

I bought a Mongoose Dolomite as an experiment.
Bottom line - It's poorly made, assembled, and designed.
Here is what I learned.

1. Four inch tires have no benefit of any kind in normal riding. (At least the tires on this bike anyway.  I didn't try in sand or snow so maybe there is some value somewhere.).
   I was hoping to find a tire pressure that would be super comfortable - roll over cracks and bumps.
   I experimented with tire pressures ranging from the recommended pressure to just 5 pounds in 5 pound increments. At the recommended pressure the tires were so bouncy the ride was very rough. At 5 pounds the pressure was so low the tire wanted to crawl off the rim and steering was dangerous. There was no happy place it was always too bumpy or too soft.
2. The bikes parts are poor quality.
   From the wet noodle cranks arms to the stove pipe steel frame there was nothing close to adequate in component quality.
3. Nothing was assembled correctly.
   To get this bike adjusted correctly everything has to be lubricated and adjusted. Every bearing group (always too tight), every cable, every nut and bolt has to be checked and adjusted.
4. The gearing was wrong.
   The stock chain ring was too large causing the gearing to be a higher range (too hard to pedal) than worked well on the bike. I replace the wet noodle crank arms with a slightly better crank arms that had a triple chain ring and only used the smallest chain ring. This allowed the bike to be ride-able.(Sorry, I don't remember the tooth numbers. I made a video about my experience - should I link to it?).

Note: These are issues common to department store bikes.

If you enjoy attracting a lot of attention while riding your bike this is the bike to have. The fat tires drew a lot of attention.

Finding the right bike
mikes has a good suggestion - a used older steel frame mountain bike with no suspension.

Also, visit a local bike shop, more than one of them if possible. Be in "I'm only shopping" mode. Talk with them and see if they will let you test ride some bikes. This will help you form conclusions about what works for you.
There are many good bike shops that enjoy talking about bikes and helping people find the right bike for the task. If you find a shop that is high pressure or snobby just keep looking, good shops are out there.

Comment: you bought one as an experiment... for this question?? or by coincidence lol

Comment: It was a coincidence :) I bought it about two years ago.

Comment: 5psi increments are WAY too much for a fat bike tyre, no wonder you didn't find the correct pressure.  The way they behave is very sensitive to pressure, and you would notice the difference between 1psi increments.
Also bear in mind on a bike this cheap, they will also be cheap  tyres and not run tubeless.
I think you would find a properly set up, quality 4" tyre would provide exactly the 'magic carpet, ride over broken tarmac you were seeking

Comment: @AndyP That's good to know. This gives me hope to keep trying.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in assuming that an inexpensive Big Box type mountain bike will quickly fail.  There are expensive alternatives such as touring bikes with tandem wheels and custom made frames. I generally recommend older steel frame mountain bikes with no suspension. You want a brand name model. Look for names like Trek, Specialized, Gary Fisher, Bridgestone. You really need someone knowledgeable about older bikes to assist you. Some of the best manufactures went out of business or were absorbed by larger companies and their names aren't as common now. When mountain biking was in its' infancy the frames were steel to make them strong, but were still reasonably light. The design is such that the average 150-170 pound rider could do things that had never been done before (jump over logs, ride dirt trails, etc.). What this boils down to is that you riding on flat terrain is not likely to overstress the components. I would suggest having the wheels bearing serviced on a used bike purchase. Also fit the largest tires the frame will tolerate and run them at near maximum pressure.